# Clicking while holding the left click in SWING

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a game in java and it has a grid view where you can left click on a single box (the box becomes red). How can make it so that after left clicking on a box if I keep pressing the left click and move the cursor onto another box it will keep clicking. Any suggestions ? I hope I was clear. Thanks.

Comment: Um, I am confused as to what you are asking. You seem to imply that if the user moves the mouse and clicks it after the original click, the event is not firing? Code would help.

Comment: There is no code actually I am just wondering how can you do it. So my question is if you click and hold and move the cursor around how can I make it to fire click events continuously ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a [`MouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) to your component.

The [`mouseDragged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html#mouseDragged%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) method will be called when the user moves the mouse whilst holding a mouse button down. You can then check if the cursor is over another box and fill it red.

Comment: sorry for disturbing again. I tried your method it works but since I am not sure how can I can check if the cursor is on a box I cant really get it working the way I want. Do you mind helping me a bit ?

Comment: Actually it works but only colors one box. It does not keep coloring.

Comment: sure, I can help, but I'll have to take a look at your code so I can run it. It would also be better to create a new question.

Comment: I think I managed to solve it although I am not sure if it is the right way. Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042373/mouselistener-mousedragged-doesnt-work-as-expected