# MouseListener MouseDragged doesnt work as expected

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have a grid where the boxes become red (I basically want to paint the grid) when I left click, hold and move the cursor on them (i.e: drag mouse). I have the code below. When I do the mouse dragging. The MouseDragged method is called properly however only one box becomes red and nothing happens while I drag after that (although the method is still called). Any ideas ? Hope I was clear. Thanks

```
public static class DragListener implements MouseMotionListener
{



    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {


            JPanel current =(JPanel)me.getSource();

            current.setBackground(Color.RED);

    }
  }
```

This is the definition of the grid:

```
public static class GridPane extends JPanel {

    public GridPane(int row, int col) {
        int count = 0 ;
        setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));

        for (int i = 1; i <= (row * col); i++) {

            JPanel lab = new JPanel();

            lab.setEnabled(true);
            lab.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            lab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3, 3));
            lab.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            lab.addMouseMotionListener(new DragListener()); 
            lab.addMouseListener(new ClickListener());
            lab.setName(count+"");
            ++count;

            add(lab);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to keep track of the position and then set the box in the grid that the mouse is on to red. I'm guessing it is only taking the initial mouse position when you click the mouse, rather than the updated mouse position when the left mouse button is held down.

Comment: Hmm that is a valid point. Thanks. Any tips on how can I can do that ? i.e track the position of the mouse ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
public MouseMotionEventDemo() {
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
    mX = (int) me.getPoint().getX();
    mY = (int) me.getPoint().getY();
    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    mouseMoved(me);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is stemming from the fact that you are dragging your mouse over multiple JPanels, and because of how java recognizes dragging.  Java recognizes dragging by the following algorithm:

Within a single Component "c":

1. The mouse is pressed while inside "c"
2. The mouse is then moved around inside "c" - this constitutes dragging within "c"

Because your mouse is ultimately leaving one component and entering a second component while pressed, the second component never registers the mousePressed action, so it doesn't think you're dragging the mouse.  I'd recommend maintaining some flag that tells your GridPane when the mouse is pressed inside ANY of your "lab" JPanels (mousePressed()), then implement the mouseMoved() method to check that flag and color if it has been set.  Then implement mouseReleased() to reset your flag back to the normal state so you don't continue coloring after you stop dragging.

For more info on mouse motion in Java, check out this link:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html